# Android JSoup use site css for extracted div class

Tags: java, android, html, webview, jsoup

I'm currently working on an app which displays one div class of a webpage. The problem is, that this div class is (of course) not using the site's CSS anymore. No I want to add the CSS back to the displayed div class. But how can I do that?

Here is my code for displaying the "events" div:

```
    private class  LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{

    String html=new String();
    Document doc = null;
    Elements ele = null;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

            doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).timeout(100000).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Elements ele = doc.select("div.events");
        html = ele.toString();
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        String mime = "text/html";
        String encoding = "utf-8";
        myWebView.loadData(html, mime, encoding);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get "style" or "link" tags with jsoup and prepend to html data.

Comment: It was so easy and I didn't see it by myself :D

Thank you! Just parsing the style tag and then appending the events tag did the trick!